# Need to check the types of two viewmodels to see if they derive from the same base

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I have a situation where I need to see if two viewmodels derive from the same base.

Model:

```
class BaseModel;
class DerivedModel1 : BaseModel;
class DerivedModel2 : BaseModel;
class DerivedModel3 : DerivedModel2;
```

Given this model, I want to know when `DerivedModel1` and `DerivedModel3` are both from the same `BaseModel`. It is not guaranteed that these classes are in the same assembly and there may be a deeper hierarchy as well. It is also not guaranteed that I know what BaseModel is.

I've tried `DerivedModel1.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(DerivedModel3.GetType());` but as you already know this won't work because of the depth of the hierarchy.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, can't imagine how `DerivedModel1` and `DerivedModel3` could *not* derive from `BaseModel`...

Comment: True.. obviously we know the structure.. but I need a way to look at two classes during runtime and determine if they are "the same type".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it like this:

```
bool DoBothDeriveFrom<TBase, T1, T2>()
{
    return typeof(T1).IsSubclassOf(typeof(TBase))
        && typeof(T2).IsSubclassOf(typeof(TBase));
}
```

`IsAssignableFrom` will work, too, if you provide the common base, the hierarchy depth has nothing to do here.

If the `TBase` is unknown, you can climb up inheritance trees of both classes, as InBetween suggested. And then compare both trees to check if they share any common type other than `object`. It can look somehow like that:

```
public bool HaveCommonRoot<T1, T2>()
{
    var tree1 = InheritanceTree<T1>();
    var tree2 = InheritanceTree<T2>();
    return tree1.Intersect(tree2).Any();
}

private IEnumerable<Type> InheritanceTree<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    yield return type;

    while (type.BaseType != typeof(object))
    {
        type = type.BaseType;
        yield return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, all classes derive from `object` eventually. All classes has a common root, so you need to specify somehow where to stop. If you don't know the base, you can climb up inheritance trees of both classes, as InBetween suggested. And then compare both trees to check if they share any common type other than object.

Comment: @Snarfblatt: You could recurrently build a List<Type> with the base types of one of the objects as you walk up the hierarchy tree and then walk up the second object hierarchy tree until you find a match with the previously built list. If the only match is `object` then there is no "usable" common base type.

Comment: Nice, but my solution gives the greatest common base class type.

Comment: @codekaizen: The requirement was to check IF the types derive from the same base class, not WHAT is that class. So your solution is doing something bit different from what was expected.

Comment: @A. - true, but it may be that he does want the type. My solution gives the option.

Comment: May be that he wants an ice cream. Your solution is against YAGNI principle. The code should do everything it is meant to do and nothing more.

Comment: @codekazien may kill me, but I tend to agree with approach @A took and it worked swimmingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Type.IsSubClassOf` method? I am not sure if this method will return `true` for deep hierarchy levels (I think it does but can not check it at this moment) or if it will only return `true` if the specified type is the immeadiate base type. Nonetheless it is easy to implement a recurring algorithm to keep checking up the hierarchy tree until you reach base type `object`.

One more thing: You are not using `IsAssignableFrom` correctly. In any case it should be:

```
BaseModel.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(DerivedModel3.GetType());
```

`DerivedModel3` and `DerivedModel1` are not assignable as they have no relation whatsoever between them. The nearest common root is `BaseModel`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on IsAssignableFrom, its the first I've used it.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want the greatest common base type of a type hierarchy.

Here's some code to do it:

```
void Main()
{
    var t1 = typeof(DerivedModel1);
    var t3 = typeof(DerivedModel3);

    var t1Hierarchy = new LinkedList<Type>();
    var t3Hierarchy = new LinkedList<Type>();
    getHierarchy(t1, t1Hierarchy);
    getHierarchy(t3, t3Hierarchy);

    var pairs = t1Hierarchy.Zip(t3Hierarchy, Tuple.Create);
    var common = pairs.TakeWhile(p => p.Item1 == p.Item2);
    var gcd = common.LastOrDefault();
}

void getHierarchy(Type t, LinkedList<Type> bases)
{
    var baseType = t.BaseType;

    if (baseType == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    bases.AddFirst(baseType);
    getHierarchy(baseType, bases);
}

class BaseModel {}
class DerivedModel1 : BaseModel {}
class DerivedModel2 : BaseModel {}
class DerivedModel3 : DerivedModel2 {}
```

Comment: Snarfblatt basically wants to check IF the types derive from the same base class, nothing about GCD.

Comment: This isn't exactly clear, since he does mention `BaseModel` and may actually care about it. Either way, I contend this is more useful, since it can be used for the purpose as you state, as well as finding the greatest common base type.